# Chrome 30 update corrupting Asian Characters in Watir-webdriver automation

Tags: google-chrome, utf-8, watir-webdriver

Today, I updated Chrome 29 -> 30 Release and noticed that my watir scripts which reads from a UTF8 text file and paste in a text field in a web page on Chrome browser is corrupting on Asian Characters, all CJK strings. Does anyone have insights for changes for asian character handling with Chrome 30?

My watir script line that paste a string in browser looks like below. This line works fine with other non ASCII characters but corrupts Asian Characters with Chrome 30.  It still works fine with Chrome 29 or before.  It has been working as long as I know and I have been running the script since last year with every Chrome versions.

...
@browser.text_field(:id => "search_box").set(@search_str) # @search_str contains an UTF8 string
...

When I manually copy and paste in text field on Chrome 30, CJK asian strings paste correctly.

My chromedriver version is unchanged and its the latest (v.2.3) and no other environment components changed this morning.  Anyone else having the similar problem?  Actually, I noticed the issue a while ago on Chrome 30 Beta when 30 beta first started.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a bug in chromedriver: [UTF-8 characters are not properly encoded when typing into inputs in Chrome v30](https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=561)

Downgrading to Chrome 29 is a temporary solution.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  Yes, I may have to resort to some temporary solutions. Also, in the meantime, I will continue to try Chrome 31 beta and/or when chromedriver updates next time, I'll check to see whether it resolves the issue.  If not, I'll have to look for a way to consult/report a bug with the Chrome developers, somehow...  I don't know how, yet. Downgrading and passing the test isn't my option unfortunately since I'm required to test with the latest...